# Facing authetication issues after deployed code to app service

Tags: azure-appservice

I am having 2 .net core microservice application. One is for fromtend and other for backend. Both are configure with azure ad and code is already in devops.

I deployed code using azure pipelines to app service as appsetting. Json contain azure ad credentials. I configured same in azure app settings under configuration and authetication.however while running the application I am facing ‘Need admin approval’ issue.

I granted admin consent on enterprise app and app registration in azure ad. Also, i am owner  on subscription and app service.

Can I know why is it still asking admin approval?

Comment: Can you share the error which you are getting?